# Elasticsearch wildcard with a space

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a **simpleQueryStringQuery** for searching results (with **analyze-wildcard**=true). The problem is that when I try to search for a documents with "test *" (that start with "test " including the space) in the results I get "testing" document too which doesn't have the space.
I only want to get whole words of "test" or "test'space'(something else)"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not do a simple match search. It will return  document if field contains full word test?

Comment: Yes that would work but in this case I need to match like autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Below will return document which has test followed by any other word. Even simple
"query": "test" will return same result.

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "field-name",
      "query": "test AND *"
    }
  }
}
```